# comparison between RGB and Ycbcr and HSI color spaces

Tags: image-processing, color-space

can anyone explain me advantage and disadvantage of HSI, Ycbcr and RGB color spaces and a give me a short comparison about these spaces?
I know relations between these models indeed I just need a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSI and Ycbcr, unlike RGB, separate the intensity (luma) from color information (chroma). This is useful if you want to ignore one or the other. For example, face detection is usually done on intensity images. On the other hand, ignoring the intensity can help to get rid of shadows.

HSI contains hue and saturation, which are the terms that people use to describe colors. On the other hand, hue and saturation are angles, which can be inconvenient for computing distances in the color space. Not to mention that hue wraps around. Ycbcr, on the other hand, is a Euclidean space. Also, Ycbcr is what you typically get directly from a camera.

Also see [this answer on DSP stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing/2691#2691).